# Seam and Sharp Edge color (both)

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, color, selection-tools, color-management

do you guys know by any chance any addon that blend colors so i can see seam and sharp at the same time? Thanks
[image]

Comment: I doubt it, but you can put both settings on the Quick menu so that you can easily turn them on and off. Hover over each checkbox on the Viewport Overlays menu (Mesh Edit Mode Overlays in Blender 4+), right-click, and select 'Add to Quick Favorites'. Pressing 'Q' will make the checkboxes instantly available. Your suggestion could easily be confused with the default Edge Crease colour.